# Waveform.js - Algorithm for thicker lines in the waveform

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, soundcloud, waveform

I'm looking for the solution that will help to teach http://waveformjs.org/ library to draw waveforms in modern Soundcloud style.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

I assume that this could be possible to achieve with the data (which is array of floats) that Waveform.js accepts and draws [here](https://github.com/soundcloud/waveformjs/blob/master/views/waveform.coffee#L42) but I'm absolute noob in such graphic algorithms. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find anything? Looking as well...

Comment: @Micah unfirtunately, no..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the waveform.js file, just before the return of the Waveform.prototype.interpolateArray function add

> newData = renderWaveform(newData);

like this:

```
Waveform.prototype.interpolateArray = function(data, fitCount) {

  *
  *
  *    
  newData = renderWaveform(newData);

  return newData;
}
```

and then define the function anywhere you want in your js, 
you can play with the var 'plain' and  'clear'

```
function renderWaveform(data,plain,clear){
    if(data){
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

            plain = plain || 2;
            clear = clear || 1;
            var step = plain+clear;
            if (i % step == 0){
                var sum=0;
                for (var j = 0; j < plain; j++) {
                    sum += data[i+j];
                };
                var average = (sum/plain);
                for (var j = 0; j < plain; j++) {
                    data[i+j]=average;
                };
                for (var j = plain; j < step; j++) {
                    data[i+j]=0;
                };
            }
        } 
        return data;
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Hope it helps ;)

**------------------------------------------------------------**

**EDIT**

it's not in the question but and if you want everythink like soundcloud, change the redraw function (still in waveform.js):

**for the height**:

```
Waveform.prototype.redraw = function() {
      var d, i, middle, t, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
      this.clear();
      if (typeof this.innerColor === "function") {
        this.context.fillStyle = this.innerColor();
      } else {
        this.context.fillStyle = this.innerColor;
      }
      middle = this.height / 2;
      i = 0;
      _ref = this.data;
      _results = [];
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        d = _ref[_i];
        t = this.width / this.data.length;
        if (typeof this.innerColor === "function") {
          this.context.fillStyle = this.innerColor(i / this.width, d);
        }
        this.context.fillRect(i, middle - middle * d, 1, middle * d * 1.5);

        _results.push(i++);

      }
```

and in your code when you generate the waveform

**for the 2 colors**:
(please note this is my raw code, in order to help, you may need a customisation

```
            var waveform = new Waveform({
                container: document.getElementById("waveFormPlayer"),
            });

            var ctx = waveform.context;

            var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, waveform.height);

            gradient.addColorStop(0.0, "#C7AF7F");
            gradient.addColorStop(0.50, "#D0BD88");
            gradient.addColorStop(0.51, "rgba(0,0,0,0.25)");
            gradient.addColorStop(1.0, "rgba(0,0,0,0.25)");
            waveform.innerColor = gradient;

            var loadedColor = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, waveform.height);
            loadedColor.addColorStop(0.50, "rgba(0,0,0,0.50)");
            loadedColor.addColorStop(0.51, "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)");
            waveform.innerColor = loadedColor;

            var defaultColor = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, waveform.height);
            defaultColor.addColorStop(0.50, "rgba(0,0,0,0.35)");
            defaultColor.addColorStop(0.51, "rgba(0,0,0,0.15)");
            waveform.innerColor = defaultColor;

            waveform.dataFromSoundCloudTrack(player.playlist.tracks[player.i]);
            var defaultOptions= waveform.optionsForSyncedStream({
                playedColor:gradient,
                loadedColor: loadedColor,
                defaultColor: defaultColor
            });
```

Comment: thanks, this render function works like a charm ;) the only thing that is missed in description is that `interpolate` option should be enabled. Hope that your implementation is the most performant algorithm for this case :)